# Selecting particular columns in ADO using getstring

Tags: ms-access, vba, getstring

When we use getstring to get data from a recordset (ADO) then it returns all the columns.

If only certain columns are required, how do we modify the getstring statement?

Comment: THanks but i found a way
just used recordset.fields(x) to get those columns i needed

thanks for having a look

Comment: What does Access have to do with it? What environment are you coding in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a step back and build the recordset with only the fields (columns) that you want, for example:

```
strSQL="SELECT ID, FName, SName FROM Members"
rs.Open strSQL, cn

a=rs.GetString
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. GetString returns all columns of all or a specified number of rows. You'll need to loop through the recordset, getting the columns you want explicitly.

It's all in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676975(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a combination of join and getrows

```
myString = join(rs.getrows( , , myColumn),";")
```

- rsGetrows returns an array containing only the myColumn's values
- Join will transfer the array in a
  string like "value1;value2; ..."

Check the exact syntax as this was written on the fly

EDIT: unfortunately, it cannot be that straight as .getrows will return a 2 dimensions array. Are there any functions that can extract a one dimension array from a 2 dimensions one? It can be written easily, can't it?